# Issue with extension typo3_console due to not detected APCu module

Tags: typo3, apcu, typo3-console

I've TYPO3 8 installation via Composer. I'm experiencing an issue with using extension `typo3_console` v5.3.0 from CLI. For the command:

```
./vendor/bin/typo3cms extension:activate realurl
```

I get following error:

```
[ TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Exception ]                                                       
The PHP extension "apcu" must be installed and loaded in order to use the APCu backend.
```

My OS is Ubuntu 16 with Apache. I do have APCu installed, v5.1.11 . It is added to my php.ini `extension=apcu.so` and I can see it's loaded when executing `phpinfo()`. Furthermore APCu is detected in TYPO3 Install Tool → Configuration Presets → Extbase Object Cache, thus I use if for back-end caching. Looks like so far everything is fine. Btw. `apc.shm_size=16M`

Any ideas why I get this this error?

ps. when I type `php -m` in CLI I can't see APCu on the list. Perhaps this exception is thrown due to not finding APCu in the output of that commend, dunno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. PHP has a separate configuration file for CLI. APCu wasn't enable there..

You can find location of `php.ini` for CLI with this command:

```
php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"
```

In my case path to file is: `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`

assuming you already have installed APCu module, you need to enable access to it itself and access from CLI, basically those two lines of code:

```
extension=apcu.so
apc.enable_cli=On
```

After restarting Apache I was able to successfully execute commands like:

```
./vendor/bin/typo3cms extension:activate realurl
```